# RabbitMQ messages without acknowleadge/rejection block channel and broker behavior after application server restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm using AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL to inform broker about status of message. Sometimes, because of connection problems, handler can't complete basicAck or basicNack methods. After shutdown signal and restart of consumers, no messages're popped from queues. In my view, it can be result of preFetched property, that is assigned with 1. From broker perspective, Message is still appearing in Channel as unacked so it's waiting to transfer new one. Consumer processed corresponding delivery tag and is waiting for next message.

When application server is restarted, consumers work as intended. Here is another question, if new connection is created to broker, messages that are unacked in previous one will be requeued or placed in dead-queue?

Here is stacktace that leads to reset consumers:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - connection expired, class-id=0, method-id=0)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:916)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:906)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:844)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:799)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:242)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:650)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:597)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean; if you have a connection problem and the connection i s closed, any un-ack'd messages will be requeued and redelivered. If you have "stuck" messages then it most likely means your code has failed to ack a message, but the channel is still open. No, unack'd messages will not be sent on another connection, until they are either nacked or the connection closed. If things are not behaving that way, then something else is wrong. Edit the question to show your code, configuration, logs etc.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Unfortunately, it's production code so I can't share it. But still few details can be added :) Security token service is used for authentication and sometimes because of its internal processing issues we're not able to ack or reject message. ShutdownSignal appears and consumers are restarted. In my view, message is still unacked, so broker doesn't transfer next - preFetch is populated with 1. So in my view, I need to cache broken deliveryTag and invoke channel.nack. Do you recommand any solution for that issue. Is there afterRestartListener or something. I'm noob in amqp area :(

Comment: What version of spring-rabbit are you using? If the connection is closed it is impossible for a message to remain un acked. If you are using auto recovery, don’t. Spring is not compatible with it. It has had its own recovery mechanism for years before amqp-client added auto recovery. I think all supported spring-rabbit versions disable it, but you might be on an old unsupported version.

Comment: Version - 2.1.17

Comment: 2.1.x is no longer supported, but it has the code that (effectively) disables autoRecovery so something else is going on. If you get a shutdown signal for the channel or the connection, there is no point in caching the delivery tag because they are scoped at the channel level. I can't think of a scenario where a message would remain un-ack'd in that scenario. You say the consumers are restarted; it makes no sense that the message is stuck in that state. You could try calling `resetConnection()` on the connection factory to force a new connection to be created.

Comment: As I see, automaticRecoveryEnable is set to true on ConnectionFactory.

Comment: If autoRecovery is still effective (it should be disabled because we immediately close any recovered connections), you would see extra "dangling" consumers on the queue - this was a constant problem for us before we added the code to close recovered connections in 2018. We kept trying to make it compatible, but there were so many corner cases, it was like whack-a-mole; hence we decided to use a sledgehammer and close the recovered connection. I am struggling to see how it can be still a problem with that version, but try setting it to false.